# I need SQL query to find between two date and another column by name

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, difference-between-rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM claz 
WHERE student AND (BETWEEN date AND date)
```

I have this one table `claz`, and I need to search to find student records between date periods

Comment: Ok, and what seems to be the problem with what you have so far?

Comment: i need to add student column to this for find student with between date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use it like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM claz  
WHERE student = 'somevalue'
  AND date_column BETWEEN '2013/02/25' AND '2013/02/27'
```

or like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM claz  
WHERE student = 'somevalue'
  AND date_column >'2013/02/25' AND date_column <'2013/02/27'
```

But it not very clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: thanks  but i need to add student column to this for find student with between date

Comment: @krishanthaukwatta:- I am really sorry but I am not understanding your point. Could you please explain what you want? Do you want student column also to be added?

Comment: hey rahul thanks.. thats ok  this sytax is correct thank youuu..........!!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM claz
WHERE student = ?
AND date BETWEEN date1 AND date2;
```

Not sure thought what your student should match and what name your date-column has.
Couldn't test it, as I am not near my DB at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT * FROM claz WHERE student = 'BG' AND date < maxdate AND date > mindate;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM claz 
WHERE student='name' 
  AND date BETWEEN 'date one' AND 'date two'
```